# What is causing the compile error: Illegal NSTableView data source?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nsviewcontroller

After some 'cleaning' of a working app, the main window appears as designed in the `MainWindow.xib`.

- I deleted a MainWindowViewController object in IB. (was beneath Font Manager)
- MainWindow.xib has it's Custom class set to `MainWindowViewController`
- The table uses Content Mode - View Based
- The two required  methods ARE included in that implementation file
- included in header file
- Table view connection has been made to `File's Owner`

EDIT: Does the full error message give a clue? Why the NSApplication?

```
*** Illegal NSTableView data source (<NSApplication: 0x100607ad0>).
```

What am I missing? What should I check to resolve?

Image included to help visualize.

[image: Screenshot of MainWindow.xib]

EDIT 2: (New info)

I deleted the `data source` & `delegate` connection from the table view and the error disappeared. The same IB designed window opens with an empty table view.

Comment: dont make the application the tableView's data source, that is bad form, it will make it hard to expand later, make a special class (or something that you already have that will always be in 1:1 relationship with the table or the tables data) for it, and make it adopt the appropriate data source protocol.

Comment: Did you also declare the NSTableView DataSource protocol in your .h file that is both file's owner in your nib and the class implementing the DataSource methods?

Comment: @uchuugaka Yes. Thank you. I forgot to include that in description.

Comment: @GradyPlayer I don't understand, but don't think I did (intentionally) set data source to application. The dark window above is for File's Owner. When I check connections for Application, it has only one received action, Terminate. No outlets. What do you mean? (Protocol has always been in .h file)

Comment: sorry I was making assumptions that you hadn't set it up correctly... we will need more error than what you have provided, perhaps a sample project, your version of xcode etc. (if this is a bug in a developer preview release of xcode try it in a stable version)

Comment: @GradyPlayer Thanks. I asked the question because I'd run out of ideas to try to debug this issue. At this point, I've decided to re-build the main window and it's controller, start from scratch and see if it works. (It is in Xcode DP and may well be a bug)

Comment: Hmm, it sure looks like the data source is set to the application, both in the screenshot and in the error message. By default, MainMenu.xib's File's Owner is the application, not the app delegate. You have the app delegate instantiated as a separate object in the sidebar -- maybe try connecting the outlets to that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 'project' is more complicated than the documentation covers. How to add a Window Controller to the Cocoa/Core Data template and utilize this controller is not easily found.

The most pronounced symptom was that the code in the intended controller was not being executed. The 2 required delegate methods were present. `awakeFromNib` wasn't being called either.

After more research, it appears the 'missing link' is the (previously deleted) `NSObject` set to the custom class of `MainWindowViewController` or `MainWindowController` in the nib file. I'm still looking for why this needs to be or why connecting to the File's Owner doesn't make the connection.

On the one hand, we can set the File's Owner to the custom class (MainWindow)ViewController or (Main)WindowController and connect the contained views to File's Owner. This doesn't work as I expected.

On the other hand, (apparently correct) we can add an NSObject to the MainMenu.xib file, set it's custom class to the (MainWindow)ViewController or (Main)WindowController and then connect  outlets to the subviews to this object. The step of adding this object in IB is the only way I could find of connecting the window to the controller.